# Sed - How to replace special characters

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have following text to replace `For More Question Papers - Join Youtube " somechannel"` to none. I used following commands with failure.

```
sed -r -e "s/For More Question Papers - Join Youtube \&quot; somechannel\&quot;/ /" ldcq.pdf > unwatermarked.pdf

sed -e "s/For More Question Papers - Join Youtube \&quot; somechannel\&quot;/ /" ldcq.pdf > unwatermarked.pdf

sed -e 's/For More Question Papers - Join Youtube " somechannel"/ /' ldcq.pdf > unwatermarked.pdf

sed -e "s/For More Question Papers - Join Youtube &quot; somechannel&quot;/ /" ldcq.pdf > unwatermarked.pdf
```

Any fix appreciated.

Comment: `sed` works with text file input. PDFs are generally not encoded as text files. You can see that this is true if you do `less ldcq.pdf`. Edit the document that the PDF was generated from instead.

Comment: Also, for the future: enclose scripts (and strings) with single quotes, not double, unless you have a very specific reason that requires double quotes, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and to handle all characters as literal with sed see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) (but you're usually better off in that case using a tool that simply understands literal strings, e.g. awk).

Comment: There are two type of watermark. One type removed by thus method, another one cannot replaced which is in question. This is a scanned copy so there's no document fot this.